# .NET Compiler Output

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, aspnet-compiler

I'm attempting to resolve source problems and I'm attempting to figure out which version is which.  The other problem I'm running into is the output the .NET compiler generates is very unintelligible and a little frustrating.  In my bin folder i have the following assemblies:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.dll
AjaxControlToolkit.pdb
App_Code.compiled
App_Code.dll
App_global.asax.compiled
App_global.asax.dll
App_Web_1bovrrt_.dll
App_Web_cuytoyuc.dll
App_Web_gjpim9z2.dll
App_Web_k-homu1n.dll
App_Web_m_hnrikq.dll
App_Web_mqzd9_of.dll
App_Web_ogzfeeae.dll
App_Web_qa1j2ese.dll
App_Web_thkvu0ud.dll
App_Web_ztp4u54p.dll
log4net.dll
StoreProcedures.dll
StoreProcedures.pdb
```

I understand most of what the files contain because Reflector is my friend.

My question is: is there a way to tell the compiler to be a bit more "English" with the compiled names of assemblies, or even to put each page in it's own assembly?  Or is that a pipe dream?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to do a few things.

1. Make sure that the project is a web application, the compiling is much cleaner that way.
2. When you PUBLISH the site, delete all existing files, and re-publish the whole thing.  This way you can ensure that the most current DLL's are the only ones out there.
3. You can also use the FixedNames flag ([See Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx)) to get a fixed assembly name.

Answer (score 0):

Since dynamic compilation just uses some hashes in the name, my guess it that you cannot.

But you may be able to achieve your goal with [precompilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx).